# Aerospike - Implementing a "batch operation" lock

Tags: aerospike

Aerospike offers row-level locking. 
(1) Can this feature be used to implement a multi-record operation mutex/lock? 
(2) It is recommended?

**Example Implementation**
- Two UDFs, one to acquire lock, one to release it
- Application must acquire lock before starting "operation"
- Lock record can have TTL in case application fails to release lock after a 
certain amount of time.
- Write policy for executing the UDF to be set to "ALL"

```
-- return true if lock acquisition successful; else return false
function acquireLock(record, lockBin)
    if not aerospike:exists(record) then
        aerospike:create(record)
    end

    if record[lockBin] == 1 then
        return false
    end

    record[lockBin] = 1
    aerospike:update(record)
    return true
end

-- return true if lock release successful, else return false
function releaseLock(record, lockBin) 
    if not aerospike:exists(record) then
        return false
    end

    if not record[lockBin] == 1 then
        return false
    end

    record[lockBin] = 0
    aerospike:update(record)
    return false    
end
```

Comment: Have you looked into optimistic concepts like compare-and-swap (CAS) or ways to merge these records into a single one? It is NOT recommended to use locks like this. This approach would severely limit throughput to a few updates per second (max).

Comment: And most importantly: the lock wouldn't stretch over multiple records so you would have to lock both records and would therefore have to face all kind of dead-lock scenarios. The summary is: it would probably introduce more problems to your app than it would solve.

Comment: (1) Thanks for the CAS tip. I'll take a look. (2) This lock would introduce measurable latency into the overall transaction. But the op isn't that intensive, so concurrent capability should still be decent. (3) If all clients know to acquire this one lock before commencing reads/writes on related sets, only a single lock would be required. With TTL, any deadlock scenario should be mitigated. (4) I've been able to redesign my schema to avoid needing this lock, fortunately.

Comment: Glad you could adapt! Now I get that you wanted to implemented a single lock in a single record which ofc reduces risk of deadlock with the TTL, ofc. Anyways there's usually no need for this. TBH: I run stuff with optimistic concurrency but create a record for every transaction so I case something wen't wrong there is always possibility to "replay" or manually fix single records in case of inconsistency. This is common to do as scale and performance tend to be prefered in NoSQL-world :)

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt sugesstion is good. you should use the CAS operation offered by Aerospike via the generation check policy. UDF is an overkill for this. You seem to have an affinity towards UDFs. Keep in mind the overhead of them. UDFs should be used if you have some complex logic should be performed which cannot be achieved by the native API

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing several comments made by others:

Although possible, this implementation is **highly discouraged** due to poor performance. Take a look at Aerospike's compare-and-swap (CAS) feature to achieve something similar.